# Changing the default network VirtualBox assigns to VMs attached to NAT

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

By default, VirtualBox assigns a 10.0.2.0/24 address to a VM attached to NAT. Is it possible to change NAT to a different network?

This is not a duplicate question. I know it is possible to define a separate "NAT network" and assign it, but that is not what I want to do. I want to change the default network for the NAT, but I see no way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

The Virtualbox manual has a [section describing how to adjust the default NAT interface behavior](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat), *Fine-tuning the VirtualBox NAT engine*. You can alter the IP address range and submask, change the behavior of the DNS resolver, and other things.

The actual changes are made through the `VBoxManage` command (in other words, there's no GUI). For example, to change the IP address range for the network, you'd run something like this while the guest isn't running:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natnet1 "192.168/16"
```

Comment: The OP asked to change it for all of VirtualBox, and not just a particular VM. `modifyvm` subcommand fails to meet the criteria because it only changes it for a particular VM.

Answer (score 1):

For those finding this later, the manual now includes [a section on modifying a Nat network.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.1/user/vboxmanage-natnetwork.html)

You can easily modify an existing VirtualBox Nat Network using the `modify subcommand`.  For example, if you would like to modify your network so the network address is 192.168.0.0/24.

```
    VBoxManage natnetwork modify --netname vboxnet0 --network "192.168.0.0/24"
```