# Change default network settings for VirtualBox when using NAT

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

I'm running into an issue where VirtualBox is assigning a guest from 10.0.2/24 when using NAT mode. The problem is its a real network on this site.

I see how to change the setting for a particular VM. For example see, [9.11. Fine-tuning the VirtualBox NAT engine](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat) in the User Guide and "Unable to change IP range of NAT network" Bug Report. However, they only change it for a VM, and not all guests.

How do I change the default network for VirtualBox and all VMs (and not a particular VM using `modifyvm` subcommand)? I want it to apply to all VMs, past and present.

---

Here's a related question: [Changing the default network VirtualBox assigns to VMs attached to NAT](https://superuser.com/q/852350/173513). Its not clear to me if this question wants past and present VMs, or only new VMs. My apologies if its a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure if the "default" NAT network can be changed, but you could also add a NAT network: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat_service .. it can also be done from the GUI if you prefer under `Preferences->Network->NAT Networks` .. you can then specify which VM's are associated with that NAT network when you create them, through the GUI or via CLI: `VBoxManage controlvm "VM_NAME" nicX natnetwork "NAT_NET_NAME"` ...

Comment: @txtechhelp - this might be the best I can do. I'll test it on Monday. Thanks.